# If $A$, $B$ are abelian groups such that $\mathrm{Hom}(A, G) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(B, G)$ for all abelian groups $G$, must $A$ and $B$ be isomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory, abelian-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$The question is in the title. If the isomorphism $\Hom(A, G) \cong \Hom(B, G)$ is natural in $G$ then this is just the Yoneda Lemma. If $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated this is also true by the structure theorem.

However this sounds like it should be false in general, else it would imply by Yoneda that if $\Hom(A, -)$ and $\Hom(B, -)$ are (a priori not naturally) isomorphic, then they are also isomorphic in a natural way (though possibly by a different set of isomorphisms).

The question of course immediately generalizes to $R$-modules.

**Edit:** *Some context (that isn't really relevant for the question)*
I'm interested in this question in light of the universal coefficient theorem for Cohomology. A positive answer would imply that knowing all Cohomology groups of a space, *with arbitrary coefficients*, would already determine its Homology (although I think it is conceivable that this topological statement can be proven in a different way).

Comment: I 'migrated' this question from math.stackexchange (I deleted the question there) since it [had already been asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148289/for-abelian-groups-does-knowing-texthomx-z-for-all-z-suffice-to-determ)

Comment: If $A=C_2^{(\aleph_0)}$ and $B=C_2^{(\aleph_1)}$, the these are isomorphic for every $G$ iff $\alpha^{\aleph_0}=\alpha^{\aleph_1}$ for all cardinal $\alpha$. This is false under CH (taking $\alpha=2$) but I don't know if it's consistent in general (=in ZFC). In case that yields a counterexample, one might restrict to $A,B$ countable, or assume GCH.

Comment: @YCor I think Eric Wofsey commented on mathSE (on a deleted answer to the linked question) that there always is a cardinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^\kappa \neq \alpha^\lambda$ for $\kappa \neq \lambda$

Comment: Ah, thanks indeed, I should have checked before. So the question has a positive answer when $A$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$ (i.e., if for every $B$ the question has a positive answer for this given $A$); we can say that $A$ is "recognizable".

Comment: If $G=U(1)$ is a topological group, then this follows from Pontryagin duality (with $G=S^1=U(1)$, and the discrete topology on $A$ and $B$), where one remembers the topology on $Hom(A,G)$. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#The_Pontryagin_duality_theorem

Comment: @IanAgol very interesting... although I suppose that since $S^1$ has noncontinuous group automorphisms it is not possible to get the topology of $\mathrm{Hom}(A, G)$ just from the group structure.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza that’s right, the topology on Hom(A,G) is not unique. Somehow this is dual to the fact that Hom(Z,A) determines A.

Answer (score 29):

I just stumbled across the answer to this in Fuchs' 2015 book on *Abelian Groups*.

The papers

*Hill, Paul*, [**Two problems of Fuchs concerning tor and hom**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(71)90096-2), J. Algebra 19, 379-383 (1971). [ZBL0228.20027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0228.20027).

and a 1974 paper of Sebel'din that I've not been able to find, and seems to be in Russian, which means that I probably wouldn't be able to understand it even if I did:

*Homomorphism groups of complete direct sums of torsion-free abelian
groups of rank 1* [Russian]. Tomsk. Gos. Univ., Tomsk 1, 121–122 (1974)

give counterexamples where the groups $A$ and $B$ are $p$-groups and torsion-free groups respectively.

But from Fuchs' account, Sebel'din's example is fairly simple.

Let $S=\mathbb{Z}^{(\omega)}$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $A=S\oplus\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=S\oplus\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}$.

Then $A\not\cong B$, but $\operatorname{Hom}(A,G)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(B,G)$  for all abelian groups $G$.

It's a fun exercise to verify this, and for me it was an ISHTOT moment when I did, so I won't spoil it for you.

Comment: Google tells me Ishtot is some sort of Indian spirit. It does not know it as an acronym. Could you clarify?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If it's an Indian spirit, then that makes it much better! I meant "I Should Have Thought Of That".

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, you [missed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363279/if-a-b-are-abelian-groups-such-that-mathrmhoma-g-cong-mathrmhomb#comment1140857_442094) a golden opportunity to say "Oh, ISHTOT".

Comment: Is [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~esparza/abelian_groups_MO.html) (spoiler alert) the right idea?

Comment: @CarlosEsparza I don’t think Hom(Q,G) is necessarily Div(G) if G is not torsion-free. Consider that e.g., every automorphism of $G=\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$ lifts to a homomorphism $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza As Emil says, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},G)\not\cong\operatorname{Div}(G)$ if $\operatorname{Div}(G)$ has torsion, since $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},G)$ is always a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. But the important point here is that if $\operatorname{Div}(G)$ has torsion then $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},G)$ is an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: I should have also pointed out that if $G$ has torsion, then $\mathrm{Div}(G)$ may not be divisible. E.g., if $G$ is a $p$-group, then $\mathrm{Div}(G)$ is the [Ulm subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_(abelian_group)#Ulm_subgroups) $U^1(G)$, which is not divisible if $G$ has Ulm length at least $2$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek True. Although that can easily be fixed by taking $\operatorname{Div}(G)$ to be the largest divisible subgroup of $G$ rather than the group of divisible elements.

Comment: The paper of Sebel’din is available in full text here: А. М. Сбельдин, [*Группы гомоморфизмов вполне разложимых абелевых групп без кручения*](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ivm&paperid=4509), Известия высших учебных заведений Математика, 1973, номер 7, 77–84